# get auth token using dj-rest-auth when user logged in

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth, auth-token

Previously I was using `django-rest-auth` package and I was getting the `auth token` when user `log in` in response `response.data.key` and this `auth token` or `key` was working fine with the api calls as `authentication auth`

Previously for `django-rest-auth`:

```
"/rest-auth/login/"
```

was getting the `response.data.key` as `auth token` and that was working
I have stored in the cookie for later use

```
.get("/rest-auth/user/", {
     headers: {
       "Content-Type": "application/json",
       Authorization: "Token " + response.data.key + "",
       },
  })
```

It was working to get info on user and also was working when used in other api calls by setting it in

```
Authorization: "Token " + response.data.key + ""
```

But now, I'm using `dj-rest-auth` package instead of `django-rest-auth` and shifted my urls to

```
/dj-rest-auth/login
```

and I'm not getting any `key` or `auth token` that I can use for `authorization` in header.

```
.get("/dj-rest-auth/user/", {
     headers: {
       "Content-Type": "application/json",
       Authorization: "Token " + response.data.? + "",
       },
  })
```

It's not working because now I'm getting `access_token` , `refresh_token` and `user info`. I tried to use `access_token` and `refresh_token` for `authorization` in header but it's not working because I'm not getting `key` or `auth token` in response when user `log in`

Note: `django-rest-auth` is no more maintained and `dj-rest-auth` is forked from the previous one and have more functions (this is the reason why I'm switching)

How to get `auth token` or `key` by using `dj-rest-auth` package so that I can use it in the `header` of API calls for authorization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you **don't** have an `REST_USE_JWT = True` in your settings. That setting will enable JWT authentication scheme instead of a (default) token-based.

Comment: and what if i need `access_token` also for later use for social authentication then? because if I'll remove `REST_USE_JWT = True` then I don't have access to `access_token` , obviously in that case I'll get `key` . Then, Is there any token that I can use for `authroization` instead of `key` . It's like i'm stuck here, because i need `auth token`  / `key` as well as `access_token`

Comment: The `access_token` for SocialAuth is actually a completely separate thing. After logging in at the 3rd party (like google), the frontend will send you an `access_token` for that provider. This token is used to make request from your backend to the Google and retrieve user info. After that, you still issue the usual Token for this User to authenticate further requests to your backend.

Answer (score 0):

In django-rest-auth you get the key from a GET request, but according to dj-rest-auth's [documentation](https://dj-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_endpoints.html#basic), you get the token key  as a response when you make a post request to `/dj-rest-auth/login/`.

When you make a POST request to `/dj-rest-auth/login/`, you can access the key at `response.data`. But now you need to store it so you can use it in your get requests.

I recommend [checking out this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48983708/where-to-store-access-token-in-react-js) to learn more about storing tokens. How you choose to do this will depend on how to the frontend of your application is built, as the javascript needs access to the token key.

I know I'm late to answer this, but hopefully I can help someone other folks who find this.